# Google Analytics Reporting API v3 requires user to be logged in

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I am attempting to fetch our website's unique user's data from Google Analytics and then display that data along side other data in a custom graph. I have everything set up and working as long as I am logged into Google. However if I am not logged in (or another user without permissions) hits the page it fails.

Goal: I want to simply be able to query the analytics API for unique users.

Here's the snippet of code that is failing due to an error that states "Login Required".

```
gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
  'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
  'dimensions': 'ga:date',
  'start-date': '30daysAgo',
  'end-date': 'yesterday',
  'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
}).execute(function (results, resultsJSONStringified) {
  // Do Stuff...
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the Google Analytics API and most of the Google APIs you must be authenticated.   You are currently Authenticating using OAuth2 which requested access to your Google Analytics Data.  Now if someone else ran this script it would access their Google Analytics Data not the data from your site.

In this instace you only want to show your own data so I would recommend you look into using a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount).  By using a Service account you give that account access to your Google Analytics data and then it will load it for everyone no user interaction needed.

The problem you are going to have is that you can't use a service account with JavaScript. You will need to use a server sided scripting language.   Also I recommend that you cache this information. There is no reason really to run this request more then once a day.  Set it up to run at night save the information to the database or something then display it to your users then.

Comment: This is sadly what I've realized. Thank you for your answer.